# How to add processor programmatically Draco data flow in the cluster

Tags: automation, apache-nifi, fiware

Is it possible to implement processor programmatically Draco data flow in the cluster?

I am planning to automate data processor flow in the 3-node cluster, using Nifi-registry

Can you please let us know how to handle these automatically? please suggest me

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Do you mean to create custom Nifi (Draco) processors ??

Comment: Please can you clarify your question? or giving us a more detail explanation?